# How to get the number of the home preset and the transition time to it?

Tags: onvif

Through the ONVIF protocol how to find out the number of the `home preset` and the `park time` to it? There are only two methods in the specification for working with a home preset: `GotoHomePosition` and `SetHomePosition`.

P.S.: `MaximumNumberOfPresetTours` == 0 for my camera. Is `PresetTour` the only way to get this information?